SRAM2 global variables
I need to put variables in specific RAM region (SRAM2) in stm32wl MCU for data retention.
MEMORY
{
  RAM1   (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 32K
  RAM2   (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20008000, LENGTH = 16K
  FLASH   (rx)   : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 128K
}

and I would like to expect same behaviour as "normal" global variables (except they should store value after quit from low power modes).
In linker .ld file I have additionally put following code:
 .ram2 (NOLOAD):
  {
    _sram2 = .;
    *(.ram2*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _eram2 = .;
  } >RAM2

And initializing variables like this:
volatile uint32_t rfWaterCnt __attribute__((section(".ram2"))) ;

Variable has correct address (0x20008000) but have random value (should be zero after power-up but not after quit from low power modes).
What can be done here?

Just a guess... What happens if you remove the NOLOAD option?

No effect. After reprogram device value come to 0 but after power-reset have random value.

Do the terms "startup code" and "CRT (C runtime (environment))" ring a bell? You might want to do some research, and then extend your startup code to zero and/or preload that memory region. Please be aware of the specification of the C standard concerning static variables (and all global variables are static).

How is wakeup from low power mode done? Is the same startup code executed than after a power up reset?

Which low power mode are you using?  Is SRAM2 powered and does it retain its contents in that low power mode?

Normal global variables are located in the .bss section which is reset by the program startup code, somewhere between entering the reset handler and the point where control is passed to the main() function.
Assuming the setup generated by the STM32CubeIDE, there should be a Reset_Handler function written in assembly language in a file named "startup_stm***.s". This function ends up calling main(), but before that it resets the "bss" section by filling it with zeroes. Look for bss in the file (I am not including the code here due to copyright).
Hence, to reset the "ram2"-variables similarly, code must be added similar to the "bss" reset code, but with "bss" replaced by "ram2".
